# Bootstrap hr position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, position

I'm working on a site with bootstrap as a base. I want to have a hr to separate the footer but for some reason in firefox it jumps up to the middle right of the page. I don't have this issue in any other browser. [link to test site](http://www.greenacresdesign.net/test/burrage/camps.php)
![screen shot of site in firefox.][2]

Comment: It looks like you're not using the bootstrap grid for layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give the element a clear

```
.footer-hr{
    clear:both;
}
```